# upgrade module from php 4.x to 5.x?

Tags: php, module

We have (finally) upgraded to php 5.x from 4.x .  The problem is that one of the third-party modules we use doesn't load.
vis:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/somewhere/ext/myapp.so' - /somewhere/ext/myapp.so: undefined symbol: compiler_globals

Unfortunately, we do not have the source for the app, so are unable to recompile it.  Is there a way to fake it out to run on php 5.x, or are we stuck in 4.x land forever?

thanx,
      dar7yl

Answer (score 1):

i doubt so. the only thing you could do is to have php 5 and php 4 running in parallel. php 5 script would then need to call php 4 scripts to use the functions from that module. but it would be really very ugly hack.

Answer (score 0):

If you told us what the module was we might be able to offer better advice.

The only thing I can think of is either re-write it or run a php4 instance just to run this module. It seem to be reasonably easy to get php4 and php5 running on the same host with different file extensions however I don't know how well using the modules from one to another will work.

Comment: The module is immaterial to this discussion. My quandry is that they changed the module interface between 4.x and 5.x . Is there not a bridge that will allow upward mobility?
I am aware that we can run 4.x and 5.x concurrently. However we want to use 5.x features, so how do you split functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can run php5 and php4 on the same server.

[Running Apache2 With PHP5 And PHP4 At The Same Time](http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2_with_php5_and_php4)

That might be a solution for you while you figure out how to get the module working with php5.

Comment: thanks for your response.  We have (almost) solved the problem with a recompiled module.  running php4&php5 at the same time is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will not be able to make the module work without the source without hacking into PHP yourself.